# Chrome Extension - Execute simple JavaScript from popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I've created a simple page which uses a JavaScript file and the `onClick` method to display different div tags. I have a much more complex program which signs a user in using ajax, it works fine in a browser but not in the popup

The more I read, and I've read everything on the developers site that I can find the more confused I get. Chrome extensions do not allow inline JavaScript which is fine, but I'm still not sure how I can actually write JavaScript. I know it has something to do with event handlers, but even that is just me guessing.

Can anyone take this program and show me what I need to change to get it to work in a popup using "manifest_version": 2 and no hacks. How do Google expect people to use JavaScript? There really needs to be a hello world program showing how to do this.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Pop Up </title>
  
  <script src = "test.js"></script>



<style type = "text/css">

    #signout
    {
        display:none;
    }

</style>


</head>
<body>
    <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- //////////////// Log In Screen ////////////// -->
    <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <div id = "login">
        <form method="post" action="">
            
            Username:
            <input type="text" name = "user" id = "user"><br>
            Password:
            <input type="text" name = "pass" id = "pass"><br>
            <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="logInPHP()" />
        </form>
    </div>




    <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- //////////////// Sign Out Screen //////////// -->
    <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <div id = "signout">
        Your are Currently signed in.<br />
        <a href = "#" onclick = "signOutPHP()">Sign Out</a>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function logInPHP(){
            document.getElementById("login").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("signout").style.display = "inline";
}
function signOutPHP(){
            document.getElementById("login").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("signout").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `onclick` attributes directly in the HTML file. Remove them and wrap your JavaScript code into the document `'DOMContentLoaded'` event listener.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("login").addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById("login").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("signout").style.display = "inline";
    });

    document.getElementById("signout").addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById("login").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("signout").style.display = "none";
    });
});
```